How to show that orthogonal states can always be distinguished?
Hello I am learning quantum information and encountered a problem as follows:
Show that orthogonal states can always be distinguished. That is, consider a set of
orthogonal states ${|ψ_i⟩}$ with $i=1,2,3...n$. in a Hilbert space, H with $dimH ≥ n$ and construct a measurement, ${A_i}$ such that if outcome $i$ is obtained, the system must have been in the state $|ψ_i⟩$.
I am thinking about constructing a set of measurements $A_i$ such that $A_i=|ψ_i><ψ_i|$, then if we measure $<ψ_i|A_i|ψ_i>=1,<ψ_i|A_j|ψ_i>=0$. But it seems I should also consider the case where $dimH > n$, but I have no idea how this might affect my conclusion?

So are you asking if its possible to distinguish two orthogonal states in a set of $n$ such states, if the space $H$ they lie in is such that $dimH>n$? Or if orthogonality is dependent on the dimensions of the space?

I am actually interested in the former case. SInce for dimH=n it seems can be solved by what i wrote in the question, but for larger dimH, I am not sure if it might lead to different situation?

cross-posted on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/40675/55

Your answer works for $dim H = n$ and $dim H > n$ as well. The only difference is that in first case, your set of measurements forms a complete set of projectors, and in the second case it should be completed with $Q = \mathbb I - \sum_{i=1}^n |\psi_i\rangle\!\langle\psi_i|$. But it does not affect anything in the distinguishing process, since this projector $Q$ will never happen, i.e., $P(Q)=0$.
